# Typescript monkey patching doesn't work for String

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, typescript2.0, monkeypatching

I create a new interface for String to add some utility methods using the technique of Monkey-patching.

```
interface String {
  toCamelCase(): string;
}

String.prototype.toCamelCase = function (): string {
    return this.replace(/[^a-z ]/gi, '').replace(
      /(?:^\w|[A-Z]|\b\w|\s+)/g,
      (match: any, index: number) => {
        return +match === 0
          ? ''
          : match[index === 0 ? 'toLowerCase' : 'toUpperCase']();
      },
    );
  };
```

in my controller when I call this new function: toCamelCase :

```
    const str: string = 'this is an example';
    const result = str.toCamelCase();
    console.log(result);
```

I have this error :

> [Nest] 35664  - ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] str.toCamelCase is not a function
> TypeError: str.toCamelCase is not a function

what is wrong with this implementation?

Comment: I put the first code snippet on the same file .ts the interface and the String.prototype.toCamelCase = function ()....... should I put them in separate files

Comment: What do you mean it doens't work? [It's absolutely working in this playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpiqA5sg3gKGWTAHsBhOAWwgBsKBnCACgEoAuZejbAbnwF98+dJhBYAdAAcoJUmACekiONIVqdOI2QBeZDACuIBGGAkQyVhy6icBIkSgQw+qObAALYPXGPJNRMwA9ADaAHpwALQAXsgAuoFYwAA0yADkqSw+EH4BTIT2RIFMAPxsoQA6AO4APsEAghEAWrHV5QBGVa30ANQsCUn5BUyUcGAI7hxwIPIpoAAmEAAeHCD6lG3QLDoAfHiDBciOzq7I3SNj7jraugAM+wfIxWmp9wcc5+PB80tXt49ppAAMiRKtAGBBUsgOKlSABVSRKKDg1KxVh8B78AYFFjo5D8Pj4GhOZCUeQibA6NIACVoNBIAHUSFAaHNUnwEGZ6CQieI6VhhmTuGIVOQqLRwawWEA) Though, I wouldn't suggest monkey patching

Comment: @JayMcDoniel   why did I have that error when I call my str.toCamelCase(); from my controller?

Comment: Without knowing how you included the monkey patch, it's gonna be impossible to tell.

Comment: Hi @JayMcDoniel is there another way to do better than monkey patching because you wouldn't suggest it. Thank you

Comment: I just create a new .ts file put all the code above (first code snippet on it) then from my controller I call it like the second code snippet above. that's how i did it

Comment: Just create a utility method. `camelCaseString(str) => camelCasedString`. Now you don't have to worry about the `Strinig` prototype properly getting the `toCamelCase` and it's way easier to test (in my opinion)

Comment: In your controller, did you import the ts file that modified the prototype?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel please have you a complete example to follow it in my nestjs application i don't know why it don't work

Comment: Nest is just a node framework. There's nothing special about how utility methods would be used compared to other node server code, or typescript code.

Comment: @JayMcDoniel :`Just create a utility method. camelCaseString(str) => camelCasedString. Now you don't have to worry about the String prototype properly getting the toCamelCase and it's way easier to test (in my opinion) –` => I don't fully understand this, could you please provide me with a code example for this thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Rather than polluting the `String` prototype, I'd suggest creating a function `camelCase(str: string): string` that takes in the string you want to camel case and returns it after being camelCased. Something like

```js
export const camelCase = (str: string): string => {
  return str.replace(/[^a-z ]/gi, '').replace(
    /(?:^\w|[A-Z]|\b\w|\s+)/g,
    (match: any, index: number) => {
      return +match === 0
        ? ''
        : match[index === 0 ? 'toLowerCase' : 'toUpperCase']();
      },
    );
}
```

And now it can be imported like `import { camelCase } from './utilties';` and called like `camelCase('Hello World!');`

This will lead to the function being more standalone, robust, and more easily tested than trying to modify the `String` prototype, plus, prototype modification isn't common anymore.